# Installing `rJava` on MacOSX fails with "JDK is incomplete!..."

Tags: java, r, rjava

I am trying to install `rJava` on my Mac but I get the following error message:

```
[...]
checking whether javah was replaced by javac -h... no
configure: error: one or more Java tools are missing.

*** JDK is incomplete! Please make sure you have a complete JDK. JRE is *not* sufficient.
configure: error: ./configure failed for jri
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/rJava’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status
```

However, I have `java` and `javac` so I *don't* simply have a JRE:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_242-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_242
```

I am however slightly bothered by the line

```
JAVA_HOME        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
```

in `R CMD javareconf`. Because it ends with jre. Is that part of my problem?

I have done some googling but I have not found much. For example the last comment on https://github.com/s-u/rJava/issues/146 is not promising.

What should I do to be able ro run `rJava`?

Comment: I believe rJAVA  requires Java installed with the operating system.  MacOS does not have Java installed as a default.  First ensure Java is installed on the computer, then try again.

Comment: Java is installed on the computer. That is why `$java -version` and `$javac -version` does not give error messages.

Comment: Which version of macOS? Have you done the usual verify/repair in Disk Utility to ensure there are no disk anomalies? Also, which version of R (3.6.?)? Are you using plain R, or a GUI like RStudio? Which version of rJava?

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.owsiak.org/r-java-11-and-making-sure-you-can-load-rjava/ - do you really want to stick to `adoptopenjdk-8.jdk`? If you really want to do so, make sure to: `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home` and then, `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:${PATH}`

Comment: @Oo.oO No I don't really need a specific version of Java. Which one would you recommend?

Comment: @jonalv I was able to run `R` with `rJava` using most recent version of `JDK`: https://www.owsiak.org/r4-0-with-java-14-inside-macos-10-15-4 - but `11` worked fine as well: https://www.owsiak.org/r-java-11-and-making-sure-you-can-load-rjava - sometimes, people are bound to old version of `JDK` - mostly in case of some legacy codes. In that case there is no other way to stick to `adoptopenjdk` or `amazon-corretto`

Comment: Well actually, turns out  I need a version that will support Groovy and Spark. I guess I will need to run everything using Docker soon so that everything can use their own bloody version of everything... :(

Comment: @Oo.oO: But if I am to change `JAVA_HOME` (which at least some people recommend agains https://github.com/s-u/rJava/issues/151#issuecomment-395070694) how do I do that so that both RStudio and R on command line picks it up properly?

Comment: @jonalv - you can install more recent Java version and resort to macOS'es way of picking up the Java version (most recent one). This way, you will end up with the very same Java version for `RStudio` and `R`. Simply install OpenJDK that suites you best: https://jdk.java.net/archive/

Comment: I found a thread that appears to be covering the same issue [here](https://github.com/s-u/rJava/issues/153).

Comment: @jonalv JAVA_HOME should not point to JRE, point it to JDK DIRECTORY and retry

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, it is finding the `JRE` as your `JAVA_HOME`.
Just set `JAVA_HOME` to point to JDK, something like:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

Then try to install `rJava`, if that is working you can add the export in your profile startup files.

Comment: In what file should I write this in order for both R from command line and Rstudio to pick this up?

Comment: you can try the export line in terminal, where you are installing `rJava`. Once confirmed that is working, depending on the shell that you are using, in a .profile file.

Comment: Although setting `JAVA_HOME` might not be a good idea according to some, this seems to work. there shouldn't be any spaces in assignment though so: `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/` works

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and install jdk-8u251-macosx-x64.dmg from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk8-downloads.html
2. setup JAVA_HOME

Comment: Setup JAVA_HOME how, and to what?

Comment: Here is a reference https://www.baeldung.com/java-home-on-windows-7-8-10-mac-os-x-linux

Comment: It's much better to have that information in your answer itself. Right now, your answer depends on two external links, either of which may change over time